# A conflict between Cygwin bash and Ubuntu bash

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on `Windows 10`. I usually use bash from `Cygwin` but I decided to give a try to the `Ubuntu` bash available as the windows subsystem for Linux in `Windows 10`.

The problem I have is that now when I open `cmd` and type `bash` is the `bash` from Ubuntu the one the opens, but sometimes is bash from `Cygwin` what I need.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have noticed if there is a correlation on which `bash` opens and if the `cmd` has admin permissions? Also check your `set` output in `cmd` and tell us about the `Path`

Comment: instead of executing bash.exe you should be executing ubuntu.exe provided you are running 1709+

Comment: @dmb I checked the path but both `C:\WINDOWS\system32` and `C:\cygwin64\bin;` are in it. `system32` is where `bash.exe` that opens ubuntu is located and `cygwin64\bin` is where `cygwin bash` is located. The system prioritizes `system32` as expected.

Comment: @Ramhound I got this message " 'ubuntu.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Comment: You have Windows 10 Version 1709 installed?  The executable would be located in `..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe`  If it still does not work you should uninstall and reinstall the Ubuntu WSL instance.  Be sure you are using the Windows Store version not the legacy version if you are running 1709+.  I already have an answer which describes [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support) though

Comment: you could try by typing "Enviromental variables(variables de entorno)" in your Start Menu and edit the Path variable. Take out the system32 entry and try again. Yet this might break things, but you could solve it by adding it again.

Comment: The correct executable might be `wsl.exe` I am not at 1709+ workstation today.

Answer (score 1):

When you need cygwin bash run it from Mintty aka Windows Terminal.
Do not use CMD as it is anyway a not adequate Unix terminal for Cygwin process.

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-icons